# Shadowed Horizontal Line

Tags: line, shadows, horizontal

I'm looking to insert a `\hrulefill` line with a shadow. Something that looks like this:

[image]

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done in red to accentuate the effect.  Obviously, the rule thicknesses, depths, etc. are set in the definition and can be altered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\shadowfill{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hbox{\ooalign{%
                  \vrule height 1pt depth 0pt width 1pt\cr%
  \textcolor{red}{\vrule height 0pt depth 1pt width 1pt}}%
  }\hskip\fill\kern0pt%
}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
This is a test\shadowfill

or this\shadowfill

or maybe\shadowfill this

\shadowfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

ZOOM:

[image]

Comment: How can I just do a horizontal line without having to add anything in front of it? Something like \hrulefill. If I just use \shadowfill, I end up with a "Leaders not followed by proper glue" error.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo Sorry about that.  I needed to add a `\leavevmode` at the beginning of the macro.  See edit.

Comment: I tried using it as a custom footer via \renewcommand{\footrule}{\shadowfill} but it doesn't show anything at all. Is there a fix around this? (This is for the fancyhdr package)

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo Perhaps `\renewcommand{\footrule}{\makebox[\textwidth]{\shadowfill}}`.  I don't have a particular example to work with, but my guess is that the footer doesn't have a prescribed width to work with so you have to tell `\shadowfill` how long a width it should fill.

Answer (score 6):

With blurred shadows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,tikzmark}
\newcounter{fshadow}
\newcommand{\shadowfill}{\stepcounter{fshadow}
\tikzmark{XL-\thefshadow}\hrulefill\tikzmark{XR-\thefshadow}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\path[blur shadow={shadow yshift=-0.4pt}] ([yshift=-0.2pt]pic cs:XL-\thefshadow) rectangle ([yshift=0.2pt]pic cs:XR-\thefshadow);}
}
\begin{document}

\shadowfill

abc\shadowfill def
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You always with Ti*k*Z!! Your rule seems more natural, congrats!